# Android: Robolectric does not support API level 1

Tags: android, junit4, robolectric

This is my basic test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    //do whatever is necessary before every test
  }

  @Test
  public void testActivityFound() {
    Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();

    Assert.assertNotNull(activity);
  }
}
```

When I execute my test under Android Studio, with the Terminal window, I have this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Robolectric does not support API level 1, sorry!
at org.robolectric.SdkConfig.<init>(SdkConfig.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.pickSdkVersion(RobolectricTestRunner.java:320)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:296)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.access$300(RobolectricTestRunner.java:61)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:202)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
```

Gradle informations:

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 2

androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.+'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
```

I use the last Android Studio version: 0.5.8

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are several approaches for this:

1. Specify in your `AndroidManifest.xml` your `targetSdkVersion`
2. Create a custom `RobolectricTestRunner` and override `getAppManifest` method for specifying the target sdk. E.g.:

   ```
   public class MyCustomRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

       @Override
       protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {

           String manifestPath = "your_manifest_path";
           String resPath = "your_res_path";
           return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestPath), Fs.fileFromPath(resPath)) {
               @Override
               public int getTargetSdkVersion() {
                   return 18;
               }
           }; 
       }
   }
   ```

   and then use it in your `MainActivityTest` class with `@RunWith(MyCustomRunner.class)`.
3. Use `@Config(emulateSdk=18)` annotation on top of your `MainActivityTest` class.

The third approach is the simplest one, but you have to annotate all of your test classes. I personally prefer the second approach as gives more flexibility in configuring your runner.

Comment: please read the last comment: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1831
thet saying: emulateSdk removed, need to use constants=burrows.apps.example.template.BuildConfig,
sdk=21

Answer (score 15):

Based on Andrei answer I tried to solve my problem, but actually I think that @Config(emulateSdk=18) has been removed, and this is what solved my issue:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class
     , sdk = 21)
   public class SplashActivityTest {
  ......
  }
```

Comment: from yesterday experience the following works also: create robolectric.properties file (src/test/resources) and add the following: sdk=21. In this case you don't have to add to @Config at every single file.

Answer (score 4):

**Notes for Mac users**

If you are on a Mac, you will probably need to configure the default JUnit test runner configuration in order to work around a bug where IntelliJ / Android Studio does not set the working directory to the module being tested. This can be accomplished by editing the run configurations, Defaults -> JUnit and changing the working directory value to **$MODULE_DIR$**

Setup:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class FooTest {
}
```

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/Running-tests-in-Android-Studio

Comment: This fixed it on Ubuntu 14.04 too